# How do you add an object to an array using scripts in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-painless

I am trying to add an item to an array in one of my Elastic Search documents. I can do this for simple items, such as strings, but cannot work out now to add objects. Here is my current code:

```
POST /user_profiles/user_profile/12345/_update
{
    "script" : {
        "inline": "ctx._source.searches.add(params.search)",
        "lang": "painless",
        "params" : {
            "search" : {
                "test": "test2"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
{
   "error": {
      "root_cause": [
         {
            "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
            "reason": "failed to parse [searches]"
         }
      ],
      "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
      "reason": "failed to parse [searches]",
      "caused_by": {
         "type": "illegal_state_exception",
         "reason": "Can't get text on a START_OBJECT at 1:29"
      }
   },
   "status": 400
}
```

Comment: Can you show how `/user_profiles/user_profile/12345` looks like before your update?

Comment: I found the issue. It was unrelated to the query itself. The problem was that mappings for the index did not contain the additional fields.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. It was unrelated to the query itself. The problem was that mappings for the index did not contain the additional fields.